# found: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Double, Double)] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, Double)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am getting the error below

```
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Double, Double)]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, Double)]
    val testMetrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(testScoreAndLabel)
```

On the following code:

```
val testScoreAndLabel = testResults.
    select("Label","ModelProbability").
    map{ case Row(l:Double,p:Vector) => (p(1),l) }
val testMetrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(testScoreAndLabel)
```

From the error it seems that `testScoreAndLabel` is of type `sql.Dataset` but `BinaryClassificationMetrics` expects an `RDD`.

How can I convert a `sql.Dataset` into an `RDD`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this

```
val testScoreAndLabel = testResults.
    select("Label","ModelProbability").
    map{ case Row(l:Double,p:Vector) => (p(1),l) }
```

Now convert `testScoreAndLabel` to RDD just by doing `testScoreAndLabel.rdd`

```
val testMetrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(testScoreAndLabel.rdd)
```

[API Doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])